# hc05 advanced at commands control through software

Tags: embedded, bluetooth

those having hc-05 modules will know that to request an RSSI value you need to hold the button on the module down and then request the rssi using the `at+inq` command , is there any way to handle this by using software ? i am not sure what the button functionality is , i can access the at mode with it however it needs to be held to use the at+inq command .

[image]
this is a pic of the module i have and the datasheet is extremely irritating with lack of info it doesnt even show that the module has a button.

Comment: Which "button"?  The data sheet seems to show none.  If you mean the RESETB signal, this apparently has a weak pullup so you could drive it with an open collector output or an appropriate voltage bipolar one.  You're going to need to be a lot more specific to keep this question open here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i added an image of the module in the original post

Comment: That's an HC-05 on a carrier.  If you want an answer, you're going to need to provide documentation of the carrier giving details of the switch, or else trace the wiring yourself.  Likely you'll need to either use a *bare* HC-05 or be willing to solder a wire to the HC-05 or switch once you figure out what that button is connected to on the HC-05.